# Freeze row and columns in Excel (at the same time)

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I lock both column and rows at the same time using the 'freeze panes' in Excel?

I can manage to freeze either columns or rows, but not both. I can do a similar thing with "split panes",  but this isn't quite what I want.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Click on the cell just to the right of the column, and just below the row you want to freeze, and then select `View`→`Window`→`Freeze Panes`→`Freeze Panes`.

So, if you want to freeze row `1` and the column `A`, click on `B2` and select `View`→`Window`→`Freeze Panes`→`Freeze Panes`.

If you want to freeze rows `1:3` and columns `A:B`, click on `C4` and select "Freeze Panes".

Comment: The freeze panes behavior has not changed since Office 95 at least.

Comment: There is a bit of a trick though. If you already have a row or column frozen then when you click Freeze Panes you get either Unfreeze Panes, Freeze Top row or Freeze First column. You need to select Unfreeze Panes then reselect the Freeze Panes pushbutton and you will get the Freeze Panes option to freeze panes as described above.

Comment: Confirmed to work in Excel 2007 and 2010.

Comment: @martha it did change: before you had explicitly the two split lines that you could drag to where you wanted them, then freeze. Now it gives no clue how to select both, nor how to make it select two lines or more.

Answer (score 3):

**Additional Help**

[Freeze or Lock Rows and Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdf5.png)

I found it Very Difficult to figure out how to do this for the Top row ***and*** for a couple of Columns.
I did figure it out however,

First Split the panes

[image: Excel 2010]

and then move the large black Lines to the rows and columns that you want Static (or Fixed)

you can click `Freeze panes > Freeze Panes` and then click `Split`  or you can just click `Split`. if you do anything else in the `Freeze Panes` and then Try to Split it will only Give you One Thick Black Line.

if your focus is in the are that is Static (Fixed/Locked) and try to scroll you will scroll only that pane.

*I am using Excel 2010*

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Cell, from where you want to freeze the pane.
2. Click on Split, a thick bar will appear. If you see closely you will find that it has created a pane.
3. In my case I selected Cell B10.
4. Click on Freeze pane, then again click freeze pane option. There you go you have frozen a column and row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Key is to simply click the Freeze Panes button rather than select the arrow on button. Clicking the Freeze Panes button will freeze both rows and columns according to the pane you've selected, whereas selecting the menu arrow on the Freeze Panes button forces you to select only one option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA snippet that may help with this.

```
Columns("D:D").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 1
    .SplitRow = 0
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select

With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 1
    .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```